# How to use a select statment inside a case statement

Tags: sql, case-when

I will do a select statement inside my case statement like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN d.dependent_speed_type = 4 THEN (SELECT column FROM tablename) 
END
```

But this is not working.
Can I realize a select statement inside my case statement? If the value 4 is inside my column "d.dependent_speed_type" then it should be select a special value from another table. How is the right syntax?

Comment: Yes, you can use a *scalar* subquery in a `case` *expression*.

Comment: Actually, that depends what DBMS you're using.  Please tag with an indication of which you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use something that will always return one value, like `SELECT MAX(column) FROM tablename)` for example.

Comment: ok thanks it is working now...the result must be always only one value